# Ruby: what does :: prefix do?

Tags: ruby, namespaces

I was reading through the source of [Artifice](https://github.com/wycats/artifice) and saw:

```
module Artifice
  NET_HTTP = ::Net::HTTP
  # ...
end
```

line: https://github.com/wycats/artifice/blob/master/lib/artifice.rb#L6

Why not just do `Net::HTTP` instead of `::Net::HTTP`, i.e., what does it mean when you use `::` as a prefix?

Comment: I searched for this topic using the phrase "leading colons" and didn't find it initially; hopefully this comment will change that. :)

Comment: @NathanLong Interesting idea. Did it work? Please report back.

Comment: @NathanLong [It worked!](http://cl.ly/image/2b1K080v1c0L/Screen%20Shot%202015-05-18%20at%208.49.00%20AM.png)

Answer (score 244, accepted):

The `::` is the scope resolution operator. What it does is determines what scope a module can be found under. For example:

```
module Music
  module Record
    # perhaps a copy of Abbey Road by The Beatles?
  end

  module EightTrack
    # like Gloria Gaynor, they will survive!
  end
end

module Record
  # for adding an item to the database
end
```

To access `Music::Record` from outside of `Music` you would use `Music::Record`.

To reference `Music::Record` from `Music::EightTrack` you could simply use `Record` because it's defined in the same scope (that of `Music`).

However, to access the `Record` module responsible for interfacing with your database from `Music::EightTrack` you can't just use `Record` because Ruby thinks you want `Music::Record`. That's when you would use the scope resolution operator as a prefix, specifying the global/main scope: `::Record`.

Comment: Excellent answer. FYI don't worry about random down votes. There are far more meaningful things in life.

Answer (score 16):

```
module A
  def self.method; "Outer"; end
end
module B
  module A
    def self.method; "Inner"; end
  end
  A.method   # => "Inner"
  ::A.method # => "Outer"
end
```

On the specific case of Artifice, at [line 41](https://github.com/wycats/artifice/blob/master/lib/artifice.rb#L41) of the file that you've shown is defined a inner `Net` module. To keep acess to the outer `Net` module, it uses `::Net`.

Comment: Can we use multiple `::` prefixes to move to one more scope level or `::` means the very top/global level? For ex.: `::::A.method` (looks really weird). Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

A `::` operator refers to the global scope instead of local.

Comment: Thanks. I also found an explanation of the [scope resolution operator in Ruby](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#scopeofconstantsandvariables).