# When is scope resolution necessary in Ruby (ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Anyone have any idea what might be happening in this situation? Why is using `self.class` or scope resolution `::MyModel` necessary?

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :other_model
  validate :custom_validation

  private
  def custom_validation
    if MyModel.where(some_field: 1).count > 0
      errors.add(:some_field, "foo")
    end
  end
end

# ... In some other part of the code base

my_model_instance = @other_model.my_models.find_or_initialize_by_some_field("foo")
my_model_instance.save
# Raises error - MyModel::MyModel is undefined
```

The above code works fine most of the time. But for some reason, in one situation it was throwing that exception. Changing the `custom_validation` function to use `self.class` instead of `MyModel` and it works.

```
  def custom_validation
    if self.class.where(some_field: "bar").count > 0
      errors.add(:some_field, "error message")
    end
  end
```

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Why/how can the constant `MyModel` be interpreted  as `MyModel::MyModel` is this specific situation?

`Ruby 2.0.0-p195` and `Rails 3.2.13`

edited: 
Clarify/add question about why scope resolution becomes necessary.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032844/ruby-what-does-prefix-do) is pretty similar but it is still unclear to me **why** using `MyModel` without scope resolution works fine *most* of the time.

Comment: PS: I'm sorry I cannot give a more specific example. The real bug was on someone else's computer and I don't have the error in front of me anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#Ruby) so Ruby will not look for `MyModel` inside the `MyModel` namespace.

```
def custom_validation
  if ::MyModel.where(some_field: 1).count > 0
    errors.add(:some_field, "foo")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @amesee. Any thoughts on why the scope resolution is only necessary sometimes? (Wish I had a better example to give demonstrating needed/not needing it but I don't)

Comment: It's because inside the definition of `MyClass`, any constants you create or reference are assumed under the `MyClass` namespace. With `self.class` you're not referencing `MyClass` with a constant, but instead with the `MyClass` _object_ since `self.class` in your code refers to the class object of `self`.

Comment: That all makes perfect sense but I don't understand why I can normally do something like `foo = MyModel.create` and **not** get an exception.

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5033013/2081133) which explains namespaces in Ruby pretty well.

Comment: Wait is this right? I've never seen a case where you can't reference a class by name in its own body. This doesn't address the question of what situation this error happens in.

Comment: Looking at the error in @AndrewHubbs post, `# Raises error - MyModel::MyModel is undefined` shows that it is looking for a `MyModel` class inside the `MyModel` namespace (a different class than `MyModel`. But if you don't think it's right (I've been incorrect many times before :-)) then please feel free to provide the correct answer.