# Ruby on rails - how to use nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, nested-class

I have a model

```
class Company::Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def outcome_loans
    moneys.where(
      "date >= ? AND account_from = ? AND account_to = ?",
      Time.now.beginning_of_day,
      Book::Account.find_by_number('50').id,
      Book::Account.find_by_number('66.1').id
    ).sum(:outcome)
  end

end
```

and when I try to call method "outcome_loans", I get error "NameError: uninitialized constant Company::Book::Account"

How to tell Rails, that I want use "Book::Account" instead "Company::Book::Account"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, write as

```
def outcome_loans
    moneys.where(
      "date >= ? AND account_from = ? AND account_to = ?",
      Time.now.beginning_of_day,
      ::Book::Account.find_by_number('50').id,
      ::Book::Account.find_by_number('66.1').id
    ).sum(:outcome)
end
```

Now, you will be able to use the `Book` class, inside the `Company::Office`.

Read this [Ruby: what does :: prefix do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032844/ruby-what-does-prefix-do)