# Rails: LoadError - Cannot load such file (requiring a gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm import the [active_campaign gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/active_campaign) into a controller like so (already included in my `Gemfile` and ran `bundle install`):

```
require 'active_campaign'

class Website::MyController < ApplicationController
  def create
      client = ::ActiveCampaign::Client.new("url","api-key")
      # ...
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

> LoadError in Website::MyController#create
>   cannot load such file -- active_campaign

#### Removing the `require 'active_campaign'` line

After removing the require line, I now get:

> NameError in Website::MyController#create uninitialized constant ActiveCampaign

How can I get this to work?

Comment: i think you have typo instead `::ActiveCampaign::Client.new("url","api-key")` use `ActiveCampaign::Client.new("url","api-key")`

Comment: Check your load path (output $LOAD_PATH rails console for example)

Your gem needs to be located in any directory of your load path, otherwise require will fail if you don't use an absolute path.

Comment: You don't have to require explicit any gem in controller. Have you tried `bundle update` ?

Comment: @kevdev I just see a huge list of directories. How can I tell if it's located in one of those directories or not? (using Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: @FilipBartuzi just ran `bundle update`. Nothing's changed (same error)

Comment: @Зелёный I used the `::` to reference the root namespace (since I'm referencing it from within a module). If I try your suggestion I get the error: `uninitialized constant website::MyController::ActiveCampaign` (Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032844/ruby-what-does-prefix-do))

Comment: @Yazin Do `bundle update` and remove `require ...` line

Comment: Please run `bundle install` and after that `gem list` and look for the gem.

Comment: @kevdev yup, it's there `active_campaign (0.1.9)`

Comment: @FilipBartuzi same thing Filip: `NameError in Website::MyController#create uninitialized constant ActiveCampaign` (after `bundle update` and removing the `require` statement)

Comment: Just to ensure: have you killed server and run it again after bundle update? (asking because you could run bundle update on different console window...)

Comment: @FilipBartuzi OMG what a stupid mistake! That was it .. thank you so much .. Should I delete this question, or would you like to add an answer for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rails controller so you don't have explicit `require` any gems. `Bundler` does it.
Perhaps you can't access `ActiveCampaign` constant because you added gem after starting a server (so after bundler require all gems and give you access to their classes).

Ensure you do following steps:

> 1. Kill server
> 2. Run `bundle update` or `bundle install`
> 3. Run server again

Now bundler should give you access to all `active_campaign`'s classes in rails controllers

Comment: That was it! I wrote a note on my beside: _always restart the server after a `bundle install`_!