# Rails association with wrong class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I need some help here,

I have the following association on model `A::B`

```
# Model A::B
belongs_to :B
```

When I try to create/insert in the database a new instance of A::B

```
# test.log
Processing by A::BController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"a_b"=>{"b_id"=>"128"}}
  BEGIN
    A::B Load (0.4ms) SELECT  "a_b".* FROM "a_b" WHERE "a_b"."id" = $1 LIMIT [["id", 128], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ROLLBACK
```

As you can see, I'm getting rollback because Rails is searching in the wrong class (A::B instead of B), therefore it's not finding the right element in database. The error message generate in the view is `B is required`.

```
# schema.rb
create_table "a_b", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "b_id"
    t.index ["b_id"], name: "index_a_b_on_b_id"
end

add_foreign_key "a_b", "b"
```

I believe the problem is related to the name used. For some reason, Rails is considering `A::B` and `B` the same when looking for the associations.

I already try to pass the option `class_name: 'B'` in the association, but it still use the wrong class.

Just for clarification, the real name of the classes are:

```
A => edital
B => cargo
A::B => edital_cargo # (using namespace)
```

From the Rails console:

```
# The association for the class Edital::Cargo

Edital::Cargo.reflect_on_association(:cargo)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::BelongsToReflection:0x00005588f76e6f60 @name=:cargo, @scope=nil, @options={:class_name=>"Cargo"}, @active_record=Edital::Cargo (call 'Edital::Cargo.connection' to establish a connection), @klass=nil, @plural_name="cargos", @type=nil, @foreign_type=nil, @constructable=true, @association_scope_cache=#<Concurrent::Map:0x005588f76e6588 entries=0 default_proc=nil>>

# Below, how Rails generate the names (@element and @human are equal for both)

ActiveModel::Name.new(Cargo)
=> #<ActiveModel::Name:0x00007fc6285f2a80 @name="Cargo", @klass=Cargo (call 'Cargo.connection' to establish a connection), @singular="cargo", @plural="cargos", @element="cargo", @human="Cargo", @collection="cargos", @param_key="cargo", @i18n_key=:cargo, @route_key="cargos", @singular_route_key="cargo">

ActiveModel::Name.new(Edital::Cargo)
=> #<ActiveModel::Name:0x00007fc6285d28c0 @name="Edital::Cargo", @klass=Edital::Cargo (call 'Edital::Cargo.connection' to establish a connection), @singular="edital_cargo", @plural="edital_cargos", @element="cargo", @human="Cargo", @collection="edital/cargos", @param_key="edital_cargo", @i18n_key=:"edital/cargo", @route_key="edital_cargos", @singular_route_key="edital_cargo">
```

Someone already face this problem? I can only think in the options `class_name` where I could specifies the model.

Comment: This is a known side effect of Rails' autoloading combined with Ruby's constant resolution. You should be able to use the [scope resolution operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032844/ruby-what-does-prefix-do/5033013#5033013) inside of `A` to reference `B` instead of `A::B`.

Comment: @coreyward maaan, that was fast! Thank! It works! I can accept your answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known side effect of Rails' autoloading combined with Ruby's constant resolution. You should be able to use the [scope resolution operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032844/ruby-what-does-prefix-do/5033013#5033013) inside of `A` to reference `B` instead of `A::B`

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#common-gotchas