# When do you need to prefix Ruby constants with "::"? (uninitialized constant error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, constants, autoload

The error is something like `NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar` (when `Bar` is not a descendant of `Foo`).

I get that it has something to do with loading (autoloading?) constants, and I *feel* that anything inside of `lib/` is safe to not prefix with `::` because it's autoloaded (or something).

An example that just happened to me is something like this:

*app/assets/classes/base_class.rb*

```rb
class BaseClass
end
```

*app/assets/some_module/some_class.rb*

```rb
module SomeModule
  class SomeClass < BaseClass
  end
end
```

I was running a spec and got "An error occurred while loading [file]": `NameError: uninitialized constant SomeModule::SomeClass::BaseClass`.

Now, I get that it's trying to look for `BaseClass` within `SomeModule::SomeClass`. But this was working a few hours before and then stopped after no changes to these files.

So, I could just tack on a `::` and go with `class SomeClass < ::BaseClass`, but without understanding why it feels bad and then I'm like, do I need to pepper all my code with `::` all the time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby: what does :: prefix do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032844/ruby-what-does-prefix-do)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When do you need to prefix Ruby constants with "::"?

When you refer to a constant Ruby will look for it in the current module nesting.

```erb
module SomeModule
  puts Module.nesting.inspect # the current module nesting is [SomeModule] 
end
```

The module nesting is primarily set by using the `module` and `class` keywords to open a class/module.

If its not found there it will keep going upwards in the module nesting until it reaches main and if the constant still isn't found by then you'll get a missing constant error.

This error can be somewhat confusing since the message contains the module nesting where it started looking for the constant.

By prefix a constant with `::` you're explicitly telling Ruby to resolve the constant from the top level namespace:

```erb
module Bar
  def self.hello
    puts "Hello from the top level Bar"
  end
end

module Foo
  module Bar


    def self.hello
      puts "Hello from Foo::Bar"
    end
  end

  def self.test
     Bar.hello # the current module nesting is Foo.
     ::Bar.hello
  end
end 

Foo.test
# Will output:
# Hello from Foo::Bar
# Hello from the top level Bar
```

In most cases its not strictly necissary but it is a good practice though to explicitly refer to constants outside your own namespace (dependencies).

> So why did my code stop working?

Without an actual reproducable example its near impossible to tell. It can either be "programmer related issues" (you screwed up and moved/deleted/renamed the file) or it can be tied to issues with the autoloader in use. The classic autoloader was far more prone to buggy behavior due to the way it monkeypatched `Object#constant_missing`.

Comment: I didn't spend a lot of time on it, but there's no simple way to call #nesting from outside the scope of the module/class, even with #module_exec. In addition, the behavior of #nesting has apparently changed in Ruby 3.3.0. I'm not disagreeing with your conclusion, but think a better debugging example that can be used outside of the original module definition would be advantageous for future readers.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs I'm not sure I have ever heard of any other way of inspecting the module nesting.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

What you're seeing is the difference between [nesting and namespacing](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Modules) in modules and classes. You're likely getting [NameError](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/NameError.html) because of how you've nested or namespaced your [constants](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Constants). This is documented behavior, but hard to find unless you know what you're looking for.

Using `::` can often help the interpreter to disambiguate the lookup so that you don't raise an exception. However, if that doesn't work you may need to change the way you're defining your modules and classes to use nesting or namespacing appropriately for your particular application, or change the caller so it can find the correct constant.

### Bypassing Normal Lookups to Use Top-Most Constant

Ruby has a pre-defined order of lookups for various things based on scope and namespace. When you use `::ModuleName` you are essentially telling Ruby to avoid the normal lookup behavior and find the [constant](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Constants) for the `::`-prefixed module or class object in whatever it considers the topmost namespace, which is generally the top-most ancestor or (especially within irb) the constant in the [TopLevel](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/stdlibs/rdoc/RDoc/TopLevel.html).

In other words, if you want to think about it pragmatically rather than worrying about what the interpreter is doing under the hood, `::Foo::Bar` bypasses the normal lookup behavior similarly to the following code snippet.

```rb
which_foo = Foo.ancestors.pop
which_bar = which_foo.const_get :Bar
```

To avoid bike-shedding, note that this isn't *strictly* true as the lookup is really starting in the topmost scope when you invoke `::Foo`, but I think it illustrates the concept sufficiently to answer your question.

This prefixing technique can be important when you want to ensure that you aren't calling a refined object, or Ruby's normal lookup is otherwise finding a different `Foo` with incorrect behavior from within your current scope. Some DSLs such as Puppet rely on this techique to avoid namespace collisions and treat it as a best practice, but in the wild it's mostly a belt-and-suspenders approach for safety in libraries/gems rather than in applications where you *should* generally know the scope of potentially-conflicting constants or can avoid the issue altogether with sensible naming conventions.

### Considerations for Nested Constants vs. Namespaced Constants

There is a potential edge case that affects constant lookups. For example, the following are not identical in all respects.

```rb
# nested modules
module Foo
  Module Bar
  end
end

# namespaced module
module Foo::Bar
```

That doesn't really change your specific example or, at a high level, the utility value of using the `::` operator to disambiguate constants. Just be aware that the scope of the two items are subtly different, and that may affect other aspects of your code.

### See Also

- [Module/Class Nesting](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Nesting)
- [Scope of Constant Lookups](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Constants)